# How can I create Change Password block?

Tags: views, 8, users, blocks

We can create **reset password** block by `\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\user\Form\UserPasswordForm')` in d8, but **change password** block `\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\user\Form\UserPasswordResetForm')` didn't work for me.
This is my code:

```php
public function build(Request $request) {
  $session = $request -> getSession();
  $session->set('pass_reset_hash', $hash);
  $session->set('pass_reset_timeout', $timestamp);
  $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
  $expiration_date = $user->getLastLoginTime();

  $myblock = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\user\Form\UserPasswordResetForm::class', $user, $expiration_date, $timestamp, $hash);
  return array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => drupal_render($myblock),
  );
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see the two lines of code are identical, so it should render the same form

Comment: @Jdrupal updated the question

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to take a look at the buildForm method in the `UserPasswordResetForm` class, it takes some parameters.

So you must call getForm like this:

```
\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\user\Form\UserPasswordResetForm::class', $user, $expiration_date, $timestamp, $hash);
```

This is the function docs,

> $user = User requesting reset.
>
> $expiration_date = Formatted expiration date for the login link, or NULL if the link does not expire.
>
> $timestamp = The current timestamp.
>
> $hash = Login link hash.

So when those parameters are added the form should render perfectly.

Comment: it didn't work.. check my updated code.

Comment: Try to do like this in your render array.

Comment: return array(
  'form' => \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\user\Form\UserPasswordResetForm::class', $user, $expiration_date, $timestamp, $hash)
);